# add a column that counts rows in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one with threads, and the other with posts. Each post has a parent thread, so

```
select count(*) from posts where thread=x
```

will give me the amount of posts in the same thread x.
I want to have a column in the threads table that gives me exactly this for each thread, but I can't imagine how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[Denormalize it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization), then do a big update run:

```
update thread 
set postcount = (select count(id) from post where threadid = thread.id);
```

From here on, update it manually whenever a post is added/deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it.

This is a classic example of unnecessary denormalisation - it should be a trivial exercise to query the number of posts in a thread any time this is required, but to keep the number on the threads table requires updating the threads table as well as the posts table every time there is a new post.

Comment: Sorry but I wholeheartedly disagree - every bit of forumsoftware in the world does this because it **kills** your forumlisting to have to request this for every active topic, every pageview. This is a classic example of **required** denormalization.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **column(number of posts)** and update it for a record in thread table every time the post record is added/deleted in the post table for that particular thread. 
Yes. In this case, two tables will be updated every time but then, if in future you want to get the number of posts for a particular thread you can query the Thread table which saves the overhead of querying the Post records for a particular thread in the buffer and then getting a count. Because,

```
select count(*) from posts where thread=x
```

first fetches all the records for that thread in the buffer and then gives the count. Here multiple records will be read since 1 thread can have many posts. So in such case, we can update the thread table itself with the count of posts so that only 1 record is read at a time.